# object of shared pointer being deleted while instances of shared_ptr are still in scope

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, shared-ptr

I have an STL map that contains shared pointers to objects that are manipulated in multiple threads. The object the shared_ptr owns is being deleted while a smart pointer is still present in the container and/or the scope of other functions. All shared_ptr instances are passed by value (so its not a problem with a misuse of references). I was under the impression from this source [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) that as long as an instance of shared_ptr exists (that was copied from an existing shared_ptr) the object it owns will not be deallocated.

Here is basically what I'm doing:

```
/* Remove Event response in Thread A */
std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<object>>::iterator it = objects.find(id);
if(it != objects.end())
{
    std::shared_ptr<object> ob = it->second;
    objects.erase(it);

    //Do cleanup work with ob
}

/* Add Event response in Thread B */
std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<object>>::iterator it = objects.find(id);
if(it == objects.end())
{
    std::shared_ptr<object> ob(new object(id));
    objects[id] = ob;

    //Do setup work with ob
}

/* Duty Cycle Event response in Thread C (very frequent) */
//Take snapshot of objects so Remove Event does not invalidate iterators of duty cycle
std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<object>> temp_objects = objects; 
for(std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<object>>::const_iterator it = temp_objects.begin(); it != temp_objects.end(); ++it)
{
    std::shared_ptr<object> ob = it->second;
    //Access violation can (but doesn't always) occur when dereferencing ob (ob is empty)
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I misusing shared pointers or making improper assumptions about how they operate?

Comment: Are you synchronising access to `objects` in any way?

Comment: No. I figured since I was making a copy of `objects` before iterating through them it would be unnecessary. Why and how would synchronizing access prevent the objects from being deleted anyway?

Comment: See Nicol's answer. STL containers aren't thread-safe.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reference count for `shared_ptr` objects is atomic; this is required by C++11. However, what is not required is that **`std::map` operations** are atomic. They're certainly not.

It is not guaranteed that you can insert from one thread and delete from another and still maintain the integrity of the contents of the `map`. So unless you put in your own mutexes or some other synchronization, to prevent race conditions on the `map` itself, your code will break.

This has nothing to do with `shared_ptr`; that's just the symptom of the problem. This is about the `map` that contains them.

Comment: Thanks Nicol. This helped me to fix the problem. I went ahead and created [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/8715/thread-safe-stl-map-accessor) to solve my problems with concurrency.